# Updating QPixmap inside Thread While-Loop Causes Segmentation Fault

Tags: multithreading, qt, pyqt5, qthread, qpixmap

I am creating a PyQt5 parking detection warning system with a Rasberry Pi and HC-SR04 distance sensor as part of a go-kart dashboard project. I am trying to update some polygon png images (QImage) from an "ON" state to an "OFF" state if a certain distance is met, hence I am running it in a thread While-loop.

To achieve this I have an if-statement, allowing the program to set a Pixmap for the label that will hold each polygon and update it with the ON/OFF version of the image depending on the distance. However, once I keep the program running for around 20 seconds, it closes and gives me a "segmentation fault" error.

For reference, there are 12 polygons images for detecting the distance from the front of the kart (4 vertical polygons for each sensor x 3), and so far I have only tried implementing the first four (named "front_1a", "front_1b", "front_1c", and "front_1d" accordingly.

[The 4 polygons for the first sensor. When each distance is met, the polygon should turn from transparent (OFF) to green/yellow/red depending on how close it is to the kart (ON)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3efDK.png)

Distance sensor thread function:

```
    def update_sensors(self):
        sensor = DistanceSensor(24, 23)
        min_dist = 2
        max_dist = 100
        self.dist_step_01 = min_dist + round((max_dist - min_dist) / 4 * 1)
        self.dist_step_02 = min_dist + round((max_dist - min_dist) / 4 * 2)#0.1425
        self.dist_step_03 = min_dist + round((max_dist - min_dist) / 4 * 3)
        self.dist_step_04 = min_dist + round((max_dist - min_dist) / 4 * 4)
        print(self.dist_step_01)
        while self.update_sensors_started:
            total_distance = round(sensor.distance*100)
            self.front_1a_Label.setPixmap(self.front_1a_ON if total_distance < self.dist_step_01 else self.front_1a_OFF)
            self.front_1b_Label.setPixmap(self.front_1b_ON if total_distance < self.dist_step_02 else self.front_1b_OFF)
            self.front_1c_Label.setPixmap(self.front_1c_ON if total_distance < self.dist_step_03 else self.front_1c_OFF)
            self.front_1d_Label.setPixmap(self.front_1d_ON if total_distance < self.dist_step_04 else self.front_1d_OFF)  
            print('Distance to nearest object is', total_distance, 'cm')
            sleep(0.5)
```

Full project code:

```
import cv2
import csv
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
import gpsd
import vlc
from threading import Thread
import time
from datetime import datetime
import subprocess
from gpiozero import DistanceSensor 
from time import sleep

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

        self.setup_fonts()

        self.setup_window(MainWindow)

        self.setup_dashboard_tab(MainWindow)
        
        self.setup_camera_tab(MainWindow)

        self.setup_media_tab(MainWindow)

        self.initialize_ui(MainWindow)

        # Launch the GUI with Tab 1 selected
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
        self.play_startup_sound()

    def setup_fonts(self):
        # Setup font database
        QtGui.QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont("fonts/RIDGE-LIGHT-OBLIQUE.otf")
        QtGui.QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont("fonts/Ridge-Bold-Oblique.otf")
        
        self.light_30_font = QtGui.QFont("RIDGE-LIGHT-OBLIQUE", 30)
        self.light_20_font = QtGui.QFont("RIDGE-LIGHT-OBLIQUE", 20)
        self.speed_font = QtGui.QFont("Ridge-Bold-Oblique", 120)
        
    def setup_window(self, MainWindow):
        # Set up the main window
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1024, 600)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1024, 600))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1024, 600))
        MainWindow.setTabletTracking(True)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(9, 8, 4);")

        # Set up the central widget (main container)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        # Set up tab widget
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-10, -30, 1041, 631))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")

        # General setup
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def setup_dashboard_tab(self, MainWindow):
        # Setting up Tab 1: Main dashboard
        self.mainDash = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.mainDash.setObjectName("mainDash")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.mainDash, "")

        # Location label
        self.locationLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.mainDash)
        self.locationLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 430, 231, 51))
        self.locationLabel.setFont(self.light_30_font)
        self.locationLabel.setStyleSheet("color:#464646;")
        self.locationLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.locationLabel.setObjectName("locationLabel")

        self.locationValueLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.mainDash)
        self.locationValueLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 480, 371, 41))
        self.locationValueLabel.setFont(self.light_20_font)
        self.locationValueLabel.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.locationValueLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.locationValueLabel.setObjectName("locationValueLabel")
        
        # Outside temperature label
        self.outTempLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.mainDash)
        self.outTempLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(730, 430, 231, 51))
        self.outTempLabel.setFont(self.light_30_font)
        self.outTempLabel.setStyleSheet("color:#464646;")
        self.outTempLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.outTempLabel.setObjectName("outTempLabel")

        self.outTempValLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.mainDash)
        self.outTempValLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 480, 381, 41))
        self.outTempValLabel.setFont(self.light_20_font)
        self.outTempValLabel.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.outTempValLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.outTempValLabel.setObjectName("outTempValLabel")

        # Speedometer
        self.speedLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.mainDash)
        self.speedLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 155, 251, 171))
        self.speedLabel.setFont(self.speed_font)
        self.speedLabel.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.speedLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.speedLabel.setObjectName("speedLabel")
        self.speedCircle = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.mainDash)
        self.speedCircle.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 110, 311, 311))
        self.speedCircle.setStyleSheet("QFrame{\n"
        "    border: 5px solid rgb(1, 203, 238);\n"
        "    background-color: none;\n"
        "    border-radius: 150px;\n"
        "}")
        self.speedCircle.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.speedCircle.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.speedCircle.setObjectName("speedCircle")
        self.kmhLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.mainDash)
        self.kmhLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 300, 91, 51))
        self.kmhLabel.setFont(self.light_30_font)
        self.kmhLabel.setStyleSheet("color:white;")
        self.kmhLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.kmhLabel.setObjectName("kmhLabel")
        self.timeLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.mainDash)
        self.timeLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 0, 211, 71))
        
        # Time label
        self.timeLabel.setFont(self.light_30_font)
        self.timeLabel.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.timeLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.timeLabel.setObjectName("timeLabel")


    def setup_camera_tab(self, MainWindow):
        # Setting up Tab 2: Camera View
        self.cameraView = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.cameraView.setObjectName("cameraView")

        #self.cameraFrame = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.cameraView)
        #self.cameraFrame.setStyleSheet("background-color: lightgreen")
        #self.cameraFrame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1024, 600))
        #self.cameraFrame.setObjectName("cameraFrame")

        self.bgLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.bgLabel.setStyleSheet("background-color: lightgreen")
        self.bgLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1024, 600))
        self.bgLabel.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.bgLabel.setLineWidth(3)
        self.bgLabel.setText("")
        self.bgLabel.setObjectName("bgLabel")

        self.overlayLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.overlayLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1024, 600))
        self.overlayLabel.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.overlayLabel.setLineWidth(3)
        self.overlayLabel.setText("")
        self.overlayLabel.setObjectName("overlayLabel")
        self.overlayLabel.setStyleSheet("background:transparent;")

        self.centerLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.centerLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(822, 105, 122, 160))
        self.centerLabel.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.centerLabel.setText("")
        self.centerLabel.setObjectName("centerLabel")
        self.centerLabel.setStyleSheet("background:transparent;")

        self.front_1a_Label = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.front_1a_Label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(819, 93, 44, 32))
        self.front_1a_Label.setText("")
        self.front_1a_Label.setObjectName("front_1a_Label")
        self.front_1a_Label.setStyleSheet("background:transparent;")

        self.front_1b_Label = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.front_1b_Label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(804, 72, 55, 43))
        self.front_1b_Label.setText("")
        self.front_1b_Label.setObjectName("front_1b_Label")
        self.front_1b_Label.setStyleSheet("background:transparent;")

        self.front_1c_Label = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.front_1c_Label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(789, 51, 65, 48))
        self.front_1c_Label.setText("")
        self.front_1c_Label.setObjectName("front_1c_Label")
        self.front_1c_Label.setStyleSheet("background:transparent;")

        self.front_1d_Label = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.front_1d_Label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(774, 30, 74, 54))
        self.front_1d_Label.setText("")
        self.front_1d_Label.setObjectName("front_1d_Label")
        self.front_1d_Label.setStyleSheet("background:transparent;")

        self.front_2a_Label = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.front_2a_Label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(860, 89, 46, 16))
        self.front_2a_Label.setText("")
        self.front_2a_Label.setObjectName("front_2a_Label")
        self.front_2a_Label.setStyleSheet("background:transparent;")

        self.front_2b_Label = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.front_2b_Label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(855, 68, 56, 23))
        self.front_2b_Label.setText("")
        self.front_2b_Label.setObjectName("front_2b_Label")
        self.front_2b_Label.setStyleSheet("background:transparent;")

        self.front_2c_Label = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.front_2c_Label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(849, 46, 67, 24))
        self.front_2c_Label.setText("")
        self.front_2c_Label.setObjectName("front_2c_Label")
        self.front_2c_Label.setStyleSheet("background:transparent;")

        self.front_2d_Label = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.front_2d_Label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(844, 25, 78, 24))
        self.front_2d_Label.setText("")
        self.front_2d_Label.setObjectName("front_2d_Label")
        self.front_2d_Label.setStyleSheet("background:transparent;")

        self.front_3a_Label = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.front_3a_Label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(903, 92, 44, 32))
        self.front_3a_Label.setText("")
        self.front_3a_Label.setObjectName("front_3a_Label")
        self.front_3a_Label.setStyleSheet("background:transparent;")

        self.front_3b_Label = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.front_3b_Label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(907, 72, 55, 43))
        self.front_3b_Label.setText("")
        self.front_3b_Label.setObjectName("front_3b_Label")
        self.front_3b_Label.setStyleSheet("background:transparent;")

        self.front_3c_Label = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.front_3c_Label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(912, 51, 65, 48))
        self.front_3c_Label.setText("")
        self.front_3c_Label.setObjectName("front_3c_Label")
        self.front_3c_Label.setStyleSheet("background:transparent;")

        self.front_3d_Label = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.front_3d_Label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(918, 30, 74, 54))
        self.front_3d_Label.setText("")
        self.front_3d_Label.setObjectName("front_3d_Label")
        self.front_3d_Label.setStyleSheet("background:transparent;")

        self.overlay = QPixmap("graphics/parking_overlay.png")
        self.center = QPixmap("graphics/go_kart_center.png")
        self.front_1a_ON = QPixmap("graphics/front_1a_ON.png")
        self.front_1b_ON = QPixmap("graphics/front_1b_ON.png")
        self.front_1c_ON = QPixmap("graphics/front_1c_ON.png")
        self.front_1d_ON = QPixmap("graphics/front_1d_ON.png")

        self.front_1a_OFF = QPixmap("graphics/front_1a_OFF.png")
        self.front_1b_OFF = QPixmap("graphics/front_1b_OFF.png")
        self.front_1c_OFF = QPixmap("graphics/front_1c_OFF.png")
        self.front_1d_OFF = QPixmap("graphics/front_1d_OFF.png")

        self.front_2a_ON = QPixmap("graphics/front_2a_ON.png")
        self.front_2b_ON = QPixmap("graphics/front_2b_ON.png")
        self.front_2c_ON = QPixmap("graphics/front_2c_ON.png")
        self.front_2d_ON = QPixmap("graphics/front_2d_ON.png")

        self.front_2a_OFF = QPixmap("graphics/front_2a_OFF.png")
        self.front_2b_OFF = QPixmap("graphics/front_2b_OFF.png")
        self.front_2c_OFF = QPixmap("graphics/front_2c_OFF.png")
        self.front_2d_OFF = QPixmap("graphics/front_2d_OFF.png")

        self.front_3a_ON = QPixmap("graphics/front_3a_ON.png")
        self.front_3b_ON = QPixmap("graphics/front_3b_ON.png")
        self.front_3c_ON = QPixmap("graphics/front_3c_ON.png")
        self.front_3d_ON = QPixmap("graphics/front_3d_ON.png")

        self.front_3a_OFF = QPixmap("graphics/front_3a_OFF.png")
        self.front_3b_OFF = QPixmap("graphics/front_3b_OFF.png")
        self.front_3c_OFF = QPixmap("graphics/front_3c_OFF.png")
        self.front_3d_OFF = QPixmap("graphics/front_3d_OFF.png")

        self.overlayLabel.setPixmap(self.overlay)
        self.centerLabel.setPixmap(self.center)



        vboxTab1 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        vboxTab1.addWidget(self.bgLabel)
        vboxTab1.addWidget(self.overlayLabel, 0,0,1,1, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        vboxTab1.addWidget(self.centerLabel, 0,0,1,1, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        vboxTab1.addWidget(self.front_1a_Label, 0,0,1,1, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        vboxTab1.addWidget(self.front_1b_Label, 0,0,1,1, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        vboxTab1.addWidget(self.front_1c_Label, 0,0,1,1, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        vboxTab1.addWidget(self.front_1d_Label, 0,0,1,1, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        vboxTab1.addWidget(self.front_2a_Label, 0,0,1,1, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        vboxTab1.addWidget(self.front_2b_Label, 0,0,1,1, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        vboxTab1.addWidget(self.front_2c_Label, 0,0,1,1, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        vboxTab1.addWidget(self.front_2d_Label, 0,0,1,1, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        vboxTab1.addWidget(self.front_3a_Label, 0,0,1,1, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        vboxTab1.addWidget(self.front_3b_Label, 0,0,1,1, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        vboxTab1.addWidget(self.front_3c_Label, 0,0,1,1, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        vboxTab1.addWidget(self.front_3d_Label, 0,0,1,1, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)

        self.cameraView.setLayout(vboxTab1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.cameraView, "")

    def setup_media_tab(self, MainWindow):
        pass

    def initialize_ui(self, MainWindow):
        """
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Dashboard"))
        self.speedLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "37"))
        self.kmhLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "KMH"))
        self.timeLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "8:36 PM"))
        self.locationValueLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SOME STREET"))
        """
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Dashboard"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.mainDash), _translate("MainWindow", "Main Dash"))
        #self.cameraFrame.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.cameraView), _translate("MainWindow", "Camera View"))
        self.locationLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "LOCATION"))
        self.outTempLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "OUT TEMP"))
        self.kmhLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "KMH"))
        self.outTempValLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "+ 25 C"))

        # Update speed every second
        self.speed_thread = Thread(target=self.update_speed)
        self.initialize_gps()
        # Update location every 10 seconds
        self.location_thread = Thread(target=self.update_location)
        self.initialize_location_csv()
        # Update time every second
        self.time_thread = Thread(target=self.update_time)
        # Update camera
        self.camera_thread = Thread(target=self.update_camera)
        #Update sensors
        self.sensors_thread = Thread(target=self.update_sensors)

        self.update_speed_started = True
        self.update_location_started = True
        self.update_time_started = True
        self.update_camera_started = True
        self.update_sensors_started = True

        self.speed_thread.start()
        self.location_thread.start()
        self.time_thread.start()
        self.camera_thread.start()
        self.sensors_thread.start()

    def play_startup_sound(self):
        player = vlc.MediaPlayer("sounds/startup_chime.mp3")
        player.play()

    def initialize_gps(self):
        print("Initializing GPS...")
        # TODO: Check for GPS status
        subprocess.run(["systemctl", "enable", "gpsd.socket"])
        gpsd.connect()
    
    def initialize_location_csv(self):
        print("Creating connection to location csv...")
        search_file = open('csv/canadacities.csv', 'r')
        self.location_reader = csv.reader(search_file, delimiter= ',')
        self.location_dict = {}
        for city in self.location_reader:
            if city[0] != 'city':
                self.location_dict[city[0]] = (float(city[4]), float(city[5]))

    def get_time(self):
        """
        # Get gps packet
        gps_packet = gpsd.get_current()
        # Extract time
        date_time = str(gps_packet.time)
    
        split_list = date_time.split("T")
        gps_time = split_list[1]
        hour_minute = gps_time.split(":")
        hour = hour_minute[0]
        minute = hour_minute[1]
        return f"{hour}:{minute} {'PM' if int(hour) > 11 else 'AM'}"
        """
        now = datetime.now()
        military_hour = now.strftime("%H")
        hour = (int(military_hour) - 2) % 10
        minute = now.strftime("%M")
        return f"{hour}:{minute} {'PM' if int(military_hour) > 11 else 'AM'}"

    
    def get_speed(self):
        # Get gps packet
        gps_packet = gpsd.get_current()
        # Extract speed
        speed_mph = float(gps_packet.hspeed)
        # Convert speed to int and kmh
        speed_kmh_int = int(speed_mph * 1.609344)
        print(f"Current speed: {speed_kmh_int}")
        return speed_kmh_int
    
    def get_current_suberb(self):
        # Get gps packet
        gps_packet = gpsd.get_current()
        # Get latitude and longitude
        lat = gps_packet.lat
        long = gps_packet.lon
        print(f"My coordinates: {lat}, {long}")
        
        curr_match = 100.00
        matched_city = ""
        # Search through location csv
        for city in self.location_dict:
            city_lat = self.location_dict[city][0]
            city_long = self.location_dict[city][1]
            lat_diff = abs(lat) - abs(city_lat)
            long_diff = abs(long) - abs(city_long)
            calc_match = abs(lat_diff) + abs(long_diff)
            if calc_match < curr_match:
                curr_match = calc_match
                matched_city = str(city)
        
        print(f"Matched city: {matched_city}")
        return matched_city


    def update_speed(self):
        while self.update_speed_started:
            # Set current speed
            self.speedLabel.setText(str(self.get_speed()))
            time.sleep(1)
    
    def update_location(self):
        while self.update_location_started:
            # Set current suburb
            self.locationValueLabel.setText(self.get_current_suberb())
            time.sleep(5)
    
    def update_time(self):
        while self.update_time_started:
            # Set current time
            self.timeLabel.setText(self.get_time())
            time.sleep(1)

    def update_camera(self):
        usingPiCamera = True
        frameSize = (1024, 600)
        vs = VideoStream(src=0, usePiCamera=usingPiCamera, resolution=frameSize, framerate=32).start()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        while self.update_camera_started:     
            self.frame = vs.read()  
            self.image = QtGui.QImage(self.frame.data, self.frame.shape[1], self.frame.shape[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped()
            time.sleep(0.1)
            self.bgLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(self.image))
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()  
        vs.stop()

    def update_sensors(self):
        sensor = DistanceSensor(24, 23)
        min_dist = 2
        max_dist = 100
        self.dist_step_01 = min_dist + round((max_dist - min_dist) / 4 * 1)
        self.dist_step_02 = min_dist + round((max_dist - min_dist) / 4 * 2)#0.1425
        self.dist_step_03 = min_dist + round((max_dist - min_dist) / 4 * 3)
        self.dist_step_04 = min_dist + round((max_dist - min_dist) / 4 * 4)
        print(self.dist_step_01)
        while self.update_sensors_started:
            total_distance = round(sensor.distance*100)
            self.front_1a_Label.setPixmap(self.front_1a_ON if total_distance < self.dist_step_01 else self.front_1a_OFF)
            self.front_1b_Label.setPixmap(self.front_1b_ON if total_distance < self.dist_step_02 else self.front_1b_OFF)
            self.front_1c_Label.setPixmap(self.front_1c_ON if total_distance < self.dist_step_03 else self.front_1c_OFF)
            self.front_1d_Label.setPixmap(self.front_1d_ON if total_distance < self.dist_step_04 else self.front_1d_OFF)  
            print('Distance to nearest object is', total_distance, 'cm')
            sleep(0.5)

    def stop(self):
        print("Exiting...")
        self.update_location_started = False
        self.update_speed_started = False
        self.update_time_started = False
        self.update_camera_started = False
        self.update_sensors_started = False

        self.speed_thread.join()
        self.time_thread.join()
        self.camera_thread.join()
        self.sensors_thread.join()
        self.location_thread.join()
```

From removing/adding certain parts of the thread function, I figured out that it is the action of setting the QPixmap that is causing the segmentation fault error.

[Segmentation fault error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tmE0.png)

Comment: In Qt, GUI widget APIs may only be called from within the main thread (i.e. the thread where the QApplication's event loop is running).  So calling `setPixmap` on a widget from a separate thread will not work.  You'd be better off using a QTimer instead of a separate thread, or if you must use a separate thread for some reason, set up a queue signal->slot connection so that you can emit a signal in that thread and then have the `setPixmap()` call occur in the main thread.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I added both the update_camera function and update_sensors function in two different QTimers that are called in the main thread. However, the GUI updates (the camera screen and the detection polygons) extremely slowly. I tried adding both functions to the same QTimer but experienced the same result. Any idea of what's causing it/how I can fix it? Thank you.

Comment: QTimer1 is for the `update_camera` function and QTimer2 is for the `update_sensors` function. I added the following in the main thread:

        self.timer1=QTimer()
        self.timer1.timeout.connect(self.update_camera)
        self.timer1.start(1000)

        self.timer2=QTimer()
        self.timer2.timeout.connect(self.update_sensors)
        self.timer2.start()

Comment: `timer1.start(1000)` looks like you're setting up the timer to call `update_camera` once per second (i.e. once every 1000 milliseconds).  Is that what you intended?

Comment: Sorry about that, I was experimenting with different values but my initial code had `timer1.start()`, without passing in any arguments. However, both `timer1.start()` and `timer1.start(1000)` still proved to be slow.

Comment: Why not try `timer1.start(100)` ?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried `timer1.start(100)` and am still getting the same result.

Comment: I trust you removed the `while [...] sleep()` loops?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I removed both the While loops and the sleep functions to attempt a faster performance.